# Large file upload to Amazon S3

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, asp.net-mvc-3

If I try to upload large files to amazon ,I am getting the following error:

> "Cannot close stream until all bytes are written"

Here is the code:

```
amazonClient = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(_accessKey, _secretKey);

fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(amazonClient);

uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest()
                    .WithTimeout((60 * 60 * 1000) * 2)
                    .WithBucketName(containerName)
                    .WithKey(fileName)
                    .WithInputStream(dataStream) as TransferUtilityUploadRequest;

fileTransferUtility.Upload(uploadRequest);
```

What is the solution for this?

Comment: Do you have the error code? did you try tracing down in the source? Ideally you should see the SDK divide the datastream into chunks and do the uploads asynchronously. 

Do you see the same result using the PutObject request?

Answer (score 0):

Try Again after increasing Connection Timeout.

Comment: Actually the exception is happening within two mins.So I dont think it is the problem with connection timeout

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the error is from AWS? Some other part of your code might be trying to close the inputstream.

Also for big uploads, try parallel uploads to S3

Comment: Yes I am sure it is from AWS only because the same code is being used even for other storages like sql.   And for parallel uploads ,I am using TransferUtility method .Still it is causing exception.Is this a limitation or is there any other way of uploading large files?